# Integral with DiracDelta gives incorrect answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If I calculate

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x - y] DiracDelta[x - z], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

I get this right answer, viz.

```
DiracDelta[-y + z]
```

But if I calculate a similar integral

```
Integrate[DiracDelta'[x - y] DiracDelta[x - z], {x, -∞, ∞},
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

I get the wrong answer 0 when in fact the right answer is

```
DiracDelta'[z-y]
```

Comment: what is `DiracDelta'[x - y]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Derivative of the Dirac Delta. \int dx DiracDelta'[x-a] f[x] = -f'[a] if a is real is given correctly by Mathematica.

Comment: All the above integrals are an (unsuccessful) attempt to implement the $\delta$-distribution into Mathematica (see, for example,  [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Delta-function) (The Wiki article on this topic is permanently edited. The latest change is dated  7, August 2023, at 22:09 (UTC).)).

Comment: Why does Wolfram Inc retain concepts that give manifestly wrong answers?

Comment: The reason why Mathematica answers wrong questions is unclear. Products of distributions are undefined, in general. Either by conventional evaluation $$\int f(x) \delta (x-z) \delta '(x-y) \, dx=-\int \delta (x-y) (f(x) \delta (x-z))' \, dx=-\int f'(x) \delta (x-y) \delta (x-z) \, dx-\int f(x) \delta (x-y) \delta '(x-z) \, dx$$  or by Fourier transform  $F(\delta delta') (k)= 1 \star k$$

Comment: The problem can be simplified further: `Integrate[DiracDelta'[x] DiracDelta[x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` also returns `0`. But the correct answer cannot be any real number.

Comment: @Davi: The product `DiracDelta'[x] DiracDelta[x]` is not defined at all since both supports are `{0}`.

Comment: Hi @user64494 , the point is that the result should not be zero (or any other real number),  but Mathematica says that the answer is zero. I understand that this is a bug that should be reported to Wolfram.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Mathematica answers wrong questions is unclear. Products of distributions are undefined, in general. Either by conventional evaluation

$$\int f(x) \delta (x-z) \delta '(x-y) \, dx=-\int \delta (x-y) (f(x) \delta (x-z))' \, dx=-\int f'(x) \delta (x-y) \delta (x-z) \, dx-\int f(x) \delta (x-y) \delta '(x-z) \, dx$$

or by Fourier transform where products go to convolutions

$$\mathit{F}(\delta * \delta') (k)= \int dk' 1(k') (k-k')$$

Perhaps its an too ambitious project, to exclude nonsensical input from the algorithm searching closed integral forms.

Comment: Product of distributions aren't undefined and  lead sometimes to distributions.

Comment: If $y=z$, then all the products under "the integrals" are undefined since the supports are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica `DiracDelta` especially `DiracDelta'` sometimes doesn't evaluate correctly.

Often it helps to define `DiracDelta` as a limit, here  examplary

```
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]  (* eps->0   *)
```

Mathematica evaluates

```
int=Integrate[dirac'[x - y] dirac[x - z], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> eps > 0 ]
(*(E^(-((y - z)^2/(4 eps))) (y - z))/(4 eps^(3/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]])*)
```

Result is identical to `dirac[(y-z)/Sqrt[2]] (y-z)/eps` and "diverges" for `eps->0`

But result is a distribution too, because `int==-1/2 dirac'[(y - z)/Sqrt[2]]=!=dirac'[z-y]`  and "confirms" expectation of QP !

Hope it helps!

Comment: How about `Limit[(E^(-((y - z)^2/(4 eps))) (y - z))/(4 eps^(3/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]]), 
 eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
 Assumptions -> {y, z} \[Element] Reals]` which results in `0`?

Comment: @user64494 Similar  `Limit[DiracDelta[x], x -> 0]` gives `0` too, but doesn't disprove distribution theory!

Comment: This is not similar, that's another story.

Comment: It's the same story, both expressions are distributions!